# plotting 2 curves; solid lines instead of dotted

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot two functions in a graph.

```
r <- rnorm(20,0,1)
z <- c(1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1)
data <- as.data.frame(na.omit(cbind(z, r)))
series1 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2]*data[,1])))
series2 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2])))
```

The plot of series2 looks like this.
[image]

Combining the two curves in one graph with

```
matplot(cbind(series1, series2), xaxt = "n", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Value", col = 1:3, ann = FALSE, type = 'l')
```

gives this:

[image]

The curve of series2 is now a dotted line.

I have two questions:

1) How can I change the dotted line into a solid line?

2) The titles for the axis are not shown in either of the graphs. How can I fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should give you the desired results:

```
matplot(cbind(series1, series2), xaxt = "n", xlab = "Time", 
        ylab = "Value", col = 1:3, ann = TRUE, type = 'l', 
        lty = 1)
```

[image: lines]

The key options are:

- `ann = TRUE`
- `type = 'l'`

Comment: `lty=1` is also quite essential, to have solid line. Note you can use `lty="solid"` or `lty="dotted"` as well. Finally, I would add `las=1` to have horizontal axis labels and `lwd=2` to have slightly thicker lines.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `matplot` you could use `plot` in combination with `lines`:

```
plot(series1, xlab="Time", ylab="Value", xaxt="n")
lines(series2, col="red")
```

this gives:

[image]

---

On a side note: always use `set.seed()` when using randomly genereated values. You could do that like this:

```
set.seed(1)
r <- rnorm(20,0,1)
z <- c(1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1)
data <- as.data.frame(na.omit(cbind(z, r)))
series1 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2]*data[,1])))
series2 <- ts(cumsum(c(1,data[,2])))
```

This makes it easier for other to replicate you example dataset.